# TextView wrap_content is not working in recycler view item

Tags: android

I have a big problem in making simple recycler view.
Here is the things.

I have many lines in textview3 & textview4.

[It has over 5 lines but it is shown only 3 or 4 lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ8EI.jpg)
even if i've already set maxLines=5

this is my code

RecyclerView's item

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/status_layout"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="TextView 3-1 TextView 3-2 TextView 3-3 TextView 3-4 TextView 3-5 TextView 3-6 TextView 3-7 TextView 3-8 TextView 3-9 TextView 3-10"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/status_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="5"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="TextView 4-1 TextView 4-2 TextView 4-3 TextView 4-4 TextView 4-5 TextView 4-6 TextView 4-7 TextView 4-8 TextView 4-9 TextView 4-10"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/status_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="#ff00ff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="TextView 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="TextView 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[And if i changed maxLines=5 to maxLines=4 then I can see the ellipsize.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcky9.jpg)

In list, I can't see TextView 3-10 and TextView 4-10
Why only 3 lines is shown? I set maxLines to 5.
textView3 and textview4 can be from 1 line to 5 line
So i want to set maxLines=5, instead lines=5

[List has the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qk7U.jpg)

Can I do like this?
right side textview (textview 1,2) have to be located center_vertical on list view item's height.
And left side textview (textview 3,4) have to located toStartOf textview 1, 2 and need to ellipsize if it is over maxLines (e.g. 5 lines)

[I want to like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqJE8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`? From the official documentation -

> If a dimension is set to WRAP_CONTENT, in versions before 1.1 they
>   will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will
>   not limit the resulting dimension. While in general this is enough
>   (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use WRAP_CONTENT,
>   yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In
>   that case, you can add one of the corresponding attribute:
>
> app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true|false”
>   app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true|false”

Meaning use this only when you want to use `wrap_content` but also want to enforce some restrictions to height.

Remove this line or set it false.

Comment: oh my got! you are my lifesaver.

Comment: I've just known android:layout_height="wrap_content" is same with android:layout_height="wrap_content" and app:layout_constrainedHeight="false". (I use this because layout_height="0dp" & constraintHeight_default="wrap" is deprecated.)Thanks a lot! I wasted all day! Thank you so much!!